# Java Compiling File Directory Issues

Tags: java, file, compilation, directory, cmd

I'm just a guy trying to learn some Java. The actual coding part works just fine for me, and until now I've been working in Eclipse (to new guys like myself, Eclipse is a really great free piece of software for writing and compiling code). But Eclipse compiles the code by itself, and I'm determined to learn how to do this without any training wheels, seeing as I'll probably need to do so someday. However, I already tried manually compiling my code with Command Prompt a few months ago, and ultimately I just got tired of banging my head against the brick wall. It seems that when I try to compile a simple HelloWorld file in cmd, everything that can go wrong, does go wrong. And it seems that I'm not the only one who keeps getting thrown off code because of this ridiculous first hurdle. Until now I've slowly been able to work around everything that keeps popping up, but this new problem is completely beyond any advice that I can find on the Internet.

I have my HelloWorld class ready to run. It is in the same file as my .java file. I have managed to compile it with the use of an environment variable specifying the location of the javac tool. Now all I need to do is invoke the java tool to run the file.

Creating a new environment variable specifying the location of java gives the following error message on cmd:

> "Error: could not open 'C:\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'"

I have no idea why it's picking this directory, leaping straight to \lib instead of going through \Program Files.

Specifying the location of the java tool in cmd, as my book tells me to do, gives the following error message:

> "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an external command, operable program, or batch file."

which of course is only the case because I'm trying to specify the path leading to the java tool, whilst my command directory has already been confined to 'C:\Java Code', the location of my class file, which is necessary because that's the file I'm trying to run.

So in short, the only way around this I can see is to specify two command directories at once, which I'm pretty sure is impossible.

**Solution**
In my case, this was solved by two things; first re-installing Java. It seems that I was using the wrong architecture version (Oracle's site may have been assuming that my computer was 32 bit). This seemed to deal with the 'cannot find jvm.cfg issue'. Second, configuring the system variables as described in one of the responses and on [this page](http://vietpad.sourceforge.net/javaonwindows.html)

Comment: I'm not expert in configuring Java, but the error `"'C:\Program' is not recognized [...]` usually indicates that you have not quoted your path correctly. Rather than `C:\Program Files\blah\blah`, it should be `"C:\Program Files\blah\blah"`. Even better is to use the appropriate environment variable, i.e. `"%ProgramFiles%\blah\blah"`.

Comment: btw, what do you need the jvm.cfg for? Just make sure `javac` and `java` are in your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I had exactly the same problem with compiling my code for the first time. jvm.cfg is always a difficult file. The way i fixed it was: To edit the `PATH` variable or `JAVA_HOME` to the path to jvm.cfg. jvm.cfg is a configuration file for java.

Comment: Well I've created the environment variables JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH, and I've also listed the JAVA_HOME variable in the value of the path variable. It still seems to be failing. Whilst investigating the file that won't open; jvm.cfg, I cannot find it on my harddrive. It certainly isn't under C:\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg.

Comment: ok, if u can't find it on ur hard drive, then u dont have it. re-download it to that directory and it should work. btw @Ingo jvm.cfg is essential for java, as it is the java virtual machine that allows java to run on all platforms